# focus a select on any option selected from other select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 selects and what I need is to focus the 2nd select when selecting any option from the 1st select. My code is bellow as a sinpet code but it only set focus the 2nd select when a value is a number.

```js
var acti = document.getElementById('activity');
var tip = document.getElementById('type');

activity.onchange = function () {
    switch (this.value) {
        case '1':
            type.focus();
            break;        
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="activity">
    <option value="" selected="">choose one</option>
    <option value="1">Act 1</option>
    <option value="2">Act 2</option>
    <option value="3">Act 3</option>
    <option value="4">Act 4</option>
</select>
<select id="type">
    <option value="">choose one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So just remove the switch, and do `type.focus()` on every selection ?`

Comment: isn't variable `type` undefined here?

Comment: @Miloshio Agreed, it should be tip.focus().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
$('#activity').change(function(){ $('#type').focus() })
```

```js
$('#activity').change(function(){
    $('#type').focus()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="activity">
    <option value="" selected="">choose one</option>
    <option value="1">Act 1</option>
    <option value="2">Act 2</option>
    <option value="3">Act 3</option>
    <option value="4">Act 4</option>
</select>
<select id="type">
    <option value="">choose one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @j08691, it works fine. adeneo solution works too, but this have less code.

Answer (score 0):

This works: 
Als note when you run this snippet only case '1': will trigger the focus with this code.

```js
var acti = document.getElementById('activity');
var tip = document.getElementById('type');

acti.onchange = function () {
    switch (this.value) {
        case '1':
            tip.focus();
            break;        
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="activity">
    <option value="" selected="">choose one</option>
    <option value="1">Act 1</option>
    <option value="2">Act 2</option>
    <option value="3">Act 3</option>
    <option value="4">Act 4</option>
</select>
<select id="type">
    <option value="">choose one</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks @adeneo this works, but j08691 solution works too with less code.